# How to create a silent switch override?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiswitch, avaudiosession

I have users complaining that there is no sound in my application. I found that this is usually because the silent switch is turned on, and with the handy reply tool I can usually tell them this... however this seem to be an ongoing issue and I need to fix this. I found a way to disable the silent switch with the following code.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation


class InitialViewController: UIViewController {

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            //print("AVAudioSession Category Playback OK")
            do {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
                //print("AVAudioSession is Active")
            } catch _ as NSError {
                //print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        } catch _ as NSError {
            //print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Fortunately, this code works, but I want users to still have control over whether this code is enabled or not. By default, I want it enabled and let the users toggle this feature on or off. For my other view controller I have this:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class CustomTableView: UITableViewController {

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let OverrideSwitch2 = "OverrideSwitch2"

    @IBOutlet weak var OverrideSwitch: UISwitch!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let fixFin = defaults.value(forKey: OverrideSwitch2) {
            OverrideSwitch.isOn = fixFin as! Bool
        }

    }
    @IBAction func `switch`(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        defaults.set(sender.isOn, forKey: "OverrideSwitch2")
        if (sender.isOn == true){
            //Code to switch feature on
        } else {
            //Code to switch feature off
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I have set up an `NSUserDefault` on the switch so the project remembers the preference, and since it's a simple boolean I could just paste the code in both switch states with one being 'false.' However, this switch is on another view controller and I need my code to be on the initial view controller, otherwise the code doesn't work until the user goes into preferences to change it. I need some help on setting up a switch that can toggle this code on/off and for the UserDefault to remember it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I can't believe I figured it out, but I just created another UserDefault that would set a boolean. If true, the code for the AVAudioSession gets run. If false, nothing gets executed. This UserDefault gets toggled through the switch, which also has a UserDefault to remember the switch state.

The Code is as follows:

```css
import UIKit
import CoreGraphics
import AVFoundation



class CustomTableView: UITableViewController  {

    //This is for the NSUserDefaults
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let OverrideSwitch2 = "OverrideSwitch2"
    
    //This Outlet connects the Switch
    @IBOutlet weak var OverrideSwitch: UISwitch!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
//These if statements only run if one is true or false
        
        //True: AVAudioSession is initialized; Silent Switch is Overridden
        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "Key") == true {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            //print("AVAudioSession Category Playback OK")
            do {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
                print("AVAudioSession")
            } catch _ as NSError {
                //print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        } catch _ as NSError {
            //print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
        
}
    
        //False: No Code is executed, silent switch works as normal
        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "Key") == false {
          
            //No Code Here
}
        
        //This NSUserDefault remembers if the switch is on or off
        if let switchState = defaults.value(forKey: OverrideSwitch2) {
            OverrideSwitch.isOn = switchState as! Bool
        }
    }
    
    //This IBAction is connected to the switch; It toggles the UserDefault which your app will remember next time you run it
   @IBAction func switchIsChanged(_ OverrideSwitch: UISwitch) {
    defaults.set(OverrideSwitch.isOn, forKey: "OverrideSwitch2")
        if OverrideSwitch.isOn == true {
          
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "Key")
            
        } else {
            
            UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "Key")
    
        }
    }
}
```

Simply put, if you toggle the switch 'On' the NSUserDefault runs a function to initialize the session which will only run if the bool is 'true.' If it's false then nothing is run. All I need now is alert telling the user that enabling or disabling the override will only work once they restart the app.